# How do I combine columns of my dataframe to create one datetime column which I can use as my index?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timestamp

I am using Python Pandas for data analysis.

I have a dataframe taken from an excel file with 6 columns describing the timestamp (year, month, day, hour, minute, second). I want to create a pandas.datetime variable but when I do so using the pd.to_datetime() function the following happens:

**My dataframe (df) :**

```
jaar maand  dag uur minuten seconden
2005    7   1   0   0        0
2005    7   1   0   10       0
2005    7   1   0   20       0
2005    7   1   0   30       0
2005    7   1   0   40       0
2005    7   1   0   50       0
```

**What I did:**

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['jaar'] + df['maand'] + df['dag'] + df['uur'] + df['minuten'] + df['seconden'])
```

But then the items of my df.['timestamp'] series will look like this:

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00.20050701000000
1970-01-01 00:00:00.20050701001000
1970-01-01 00:00:00.20050701002000
```

What is the correct way to combine dates and why does this 1970-01-01 thing happen to my datetime? I can't set up my own time range manually because there are missing date points here and there.

**What I also tried:**

I can combine them to get the timestamp of one row, but I have so much data that I just can't use loops to do this.

```
date00 = pd.datetime(df.iloc[0, 0], df.iloc[0, 1], df.iloc[0, 2], df.iloc[0, 3], df.iloc[0, 4], df.iloc[0, 5])
```

This is my first time posting here. I hope the editing is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you have `int` dtypes so one method would be to construct `datetime` using apply with all your columns as the params:

```
In [381]:
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
df.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime(x['jaar'], x['maand'], x['dag'], x['uur'], x['minuten'], x['seconden']), axis=1)

Out[381]:
0   2005-07-01 00:00:00
1   2005-07-01 00:10:00
2   2005-07-01 00:20:00
3   2005-07-01 00:30:00
4   2005-07-01 00:40:00
5   2005-07-01 00:50:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You can set this as the index by overwriting directly:

```
In [382]:
df.index = df.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime(x['jaar'], x['maand'], x['dag'], x['uur'], x['minuten'], x['seconden']), axis=1)
df

Out[382]:
                     jaar  maand  dag  uur  minuten  seconden
2005-07-01 00:00:00  2005      7    1    0        0         0
2005-07-01 00:10:00  2005      7    1    0       10         0
2005-07-01 00:20:00  2005      7    1    0       20         0
2005-07-01 00:30:00  2005      7    1    0       30         0
2005-07-01 00:40:00  2005      7    1    0       40         0
2005-07-01 00:50:00  2005      7    1    0       50         0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) (some values are changed for testing):

```
print df
   jaar  maand  dag  uur  minuten  seconden
0  2005      7    1    0        0        10
1  2005      7    1   20       10         0
2  2005      7    1    4       20        12
3  2005      7    1    0       30         0
4  2005      7    1    0       40         0
5  2005      7    1    0       50         0

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['jaar']*10000000000
                                +df['maand']*100000000
                                +df['dag']*1000000
                                +df['uur']*10000
                                +df['minuten']*100
                                +df['seconden'],format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print df
   jaar  maand  dag  uur  minuten  seconden           timestamp
0  2005      7    1    0        0        10 2005-07-01 00:00:10
1  2005      7    1   20       10         0 2005-07-01 20:10:00
2  2005      7    1    4       20        12 2005-07-01 04:20:12
3  2005      7    1    0       30         0 2005-07-01 00:30:00
4  2005      7    1    0       40         0 2005-07-01 00:40:00
5  2005      7    1    0       50         0 2005-07-01 00:50:00
```