# How to combine year, month, and day columns to single datetime column?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, timestamp

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
        id  lat        lon      year    month   day         
0       381 53.30660   -0.54649 2004    1       2       
1       381 53.30660   -0.54649 2004    1       3            
2       381 53.30660   -0.54649 2004    1       4
```

and I want to create a new column `df['Date']` where the `year`, `month`, and `day` columns are combined according to the format `yyyy-m-d`.

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35921945/5110870), I did:

```
`df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['year']*10000000000
                           +df['month']*100000000
                           +df['day']*1000000,
                           format='%Y-%m-%d%')`
```

The result is not what I expected, as it starts from 1970 instead of 2004, and it also contains the hour stamp, which I did not specify:

```
        id  lat        lon      year    month   day  Date           
0       381 53.30660   -0.54649 2004    1       2    1970-01-01 05:34:00.102    
1       381 53.30660   -0.54649 2004    1       3    1970-01-01 05:34:00.103         
2       381 53.30660   -0.54649 2004    1       4    1970-01-01 05:34:00.104
```

As the dates should be in the `2004-1-2` format, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is an easier way:

```
In [250]: df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month','day']])

In [251]: df
Out[251]:
    id      lat      lon  year  month  day       Date
0  381  53.3066 -0.54649  2004      1    2 2004-01-02
1  381  53.3066 -0.54649  2004      1    3 2004-01-03
2  381  53.3066 -0.54649  2004      1    4 2004-01-04
```

from [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

> Assembling a datetime from multiple columns of a DataFrame. The keys
>   can be common abbreviations like [`year`, `month`, `day`, `minute`,
>   `second`, `ms`, `us`, `ns`]) or plurals of the same

Comment: This is new to me, really nifty.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, this is surprising me - it's kind of an old feature ;)

Answer (score 7):

One solution would be to convert these columns to string, concatenate using `agg` + `str.join`, and then convert to `datetime`.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df[['year', 'month', 'day']].astype(str).agg('-'.join, axis=1))

df

    id      lat      lon  year  month  day       Date
0  381  53.3066 -0.54649  2004      1    2 2004-01-02
1  381  53.3066 -0.54649  2004      1    3 2004-01-03
2  381  53.3066 -0.54649  2004      1    4 2004-01-04
```

You may also want to add an `errors='coerce'` argument if you have invalid datetime combinations between your columns.

Answer (score 4):

To fix your code

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df.year*10000+df.month*100+df.day,format='%Y%m%d')
df
Out[57]: 
    id      lat      lon  year  month  day       Date
0  381  53.3066 -0.54649  2004      1    2 2004-01-02
1  381  53.3066 -0.54649  2004      1    3 2004-01-03
2  381  53.3066 -0.54649  2004      1    4 2004-01-04
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to find a solution because I was working with a dataset with columns in Spanish. As soon as I translated them to "year" "month" and "day" and "hour", the conversion worked perfectl